# Error while mounting a component on a div instead of a body

Tags: svelte

I am trying to mount a component on a div element using document.querySelector('.widget') but it throws an error

main.js looks like

```js
const app = new App({
    target: document.querySelector('.widget'),
});
```

index.html looks like

```html
    <body>
    <script src='bundle.js'></script>
    <div class="widget" id="widget"></div>
    </body>
```

I get an error 
Uncaught Error: 'target' is a required option

Comment: In addition to @Tholle's answer, note that your selector (`.widget`) is referencing an element with a *class* of `"widget"`, rather than an *ID*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You load the `bundle.js` script before the div tag in the document. If you put the script tag after the div it will work as expected.

```html
<body>
  <div class="widget" id="widget"></div>
  <script src='bundle.js'></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Haha wow!  Caught by ancient bug. Guess I'm not onReady yet ;)